# How to set srcObject on audio element with React in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to set the `srcObject`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.less'
interface Constraints {
    video: boolean,
    audio: boolean
}
export default class MediaTransfer extends React.Component{
    private videoEle = React.createRef<HTMLVideoElement>();

    componentDidMount () {
       const constraints: Partial<Constraints> = {video: false, audio: true};
       const self = this;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((stream: MediaStream): void =>{
                console.log(stream);

                console.log(self.videoEle.current)
                self.videoEle.current.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch((err: Object):void => {
                console.log(err)
            })

   }
    render(){

        return(
            <div>
               <video ref={this.videoEle}></video>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> [tsl] ERROR in D:\workspace\webrtc-awesome\src\pages\mediaTransfer\index.tsx(18,17)
>         TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

`self.videoEle.current` can't set `srcObject`?

Comment: It seems that thre current.srcObject is not exported by the [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement). Have you tried self.srcObject = stream on an [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject)